# How to show dot when the text length in textarea is too long

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am working on a code where I need to show dots ( ... ) if the text inside textarea is too long, can any one let me know how to achive it.

Answer (score 1):

For `<textarea>` `text-ellipsis` won't work. I tried with `<p>` and it works

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="truncate">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

<textarea class="truncate">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css file, add

```
.textarea_class{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the css as

```css
.design{
  overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but iam unable to see your example. And will it work in textarea?

Comment: I tried this in my project and works for me, for my project I tried on div and span. I think It should also work for textarea.. you can try. Tell me if it helps you or not